# How to write csv file name based on month, year, time column headers in python

Tags: python, csv, namespaces, rename

This is probably an easy question for someone out there to answer. I have a bunch of csv files that I would like to rename using info from within the file.

I have a data frame `result` that looks like this:

```
              id  year  month  day  precip
0       pod_0001  2017      1    1     2.6
1       pod_0002  2017      1    1     0.4
2       pod_0003  2017      1    1     2.2
3       pod_0004  2017      1    1    25.2
4       pod_0005  2017      1    1    19.4
```

And I want the name of the file to be YYYY.MM.DD, so in this case it would look like result.2017.01.01.

How do I do that with the `to_csv` function like this one..?

```
result.to_csv("result.csv", na_rep="0")
```

Comment: To get a good answer we will need to know what format the date you want to use is in.  In the shown code you have 5 different fields.  They all happen to have the same value, but is this always the case?

Comment: Yes, it is always the case. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution may be somewhat old-schooled (it uses the `%` operator), but it works:

```
fname = "result.%04d.%02d.%02d.csv" % \
        tuple(result[['year','month','day']].drop_duplicates().values[0])
print(fname)
# result.2017.01.01.csv
result.to_csv(fname, na_rep="0")
```

Comment: do you sleep?  :-)

Comment: @StephenRauch Eh?